# Java: How arrays work

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was working with relatively large `String` arrays today. (Roughly 400 x 400 in size)  I was wondering how making one array equal to another works exactly.  For instance,

```
String[][] array1 = new String[400][400];
String[][] array2 = array1;
```

Is making one array equal to another the same thing as looping through each element and making it equal to the respective position in another array? (Like below)

```
for(int y = 0; y < 400; y++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < 400; x++) {
        array2[x][y] = array1[x][y];
    }
}
```

Now is the looping method the same thing as making one array equal to another?  Or is the first/second faster than the other?  Personally, I think the first would be faster just because there is no recursion or having to manually allocate memory to `array2` before the recursion.  But, I have no idea where to start looking for this information and I would like to understand the logistics of how Java processes these kinds of things.

Comment: Take a look at [Java Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: I also think you are confused about the definition of recursion.

Comment: Interesting but I don't see anything about this except at the bottom where it mentions the arrayCopy method which doesn't seem to have anything to do with making one array equal to another with an equals sign
Doug Ramsey: I probably am because I really don't know HOW things work as much as I know that they actually work..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not the same thing: arrays are reference objects, so `array2` becomes an alias of `array1`, not its copy. Any assignment that you make to an element of `array2` become "visible" through `array1`, and vice versa. If you would like to make a copy of a single-dimension array, you can use its `clone()` method; note that the copy will be *shallow*, i.e. the individual elements of the array will *not* be cloned (making the trick inapplicable to the 2-D array that you described in your post).

Comment: Wow... I never realized that.  That could probably explain why so many of my programs with arrays don't work the way I want them to. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 5):

`array2 = array1` doesn't make copies of the elements, only the array reference. So `array2` and `array1` both reference the same underlying array.

This is very easy to determine for yourself:

```
String[][] array1 = new String[4][4];
array1[0][0] = "some string";
String[][] array2 = array1;
array1[0][0] = "another string";
System.out.println("array2: " + array2[0][0]);
array2[0][0] = "a third string";
System.out.println("array1: " + array1[0][0]);
```

Comment: Same as @dasblinkenlight's answer but with an example. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I think when you make one array equal to another, you simply change the reference. For example:

ARRAY 1 -  * [][][][]...[][] where * is a reference to Array 1
Array 2 -  & [][][][]...[][] where & is the reference to Array 2

Then Setting Array 1 = Array 2
Array 1  Will simply change its reference to & and start reading at the memory reference &

Answer (score 1):

The second line in the first code example is creating a reference variable of type String [] that refers to the same two-dimensional array object that the reference array1 refers to. There is only one two-dimensional array in memory, but two reference variables refer to it, array1 and array2.

You seem confused about the definition of recursion, so I will point you here- [Recursion in Computer Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursion_in_computer_science).